# My OOP is not acting right

Tags: javascript, oop, three.js

I am trying to understand OOP in JS, and it is not working for me pretty well...
What I've tried is the following:

```
var worldClass = function(shape){
            this.shape = shape;
            switch (shape){
                case "sphere":
                    var tmpX = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                    var sphereModel = new THREE.Sphere( tmpX, 6);
                    var sphereGeom =  new THREE.SphereGeometry( 6, 32, 16 );
                    var boundMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff, transparent: true, opacity: 0.3 } );
                    var boundSphere = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeom, boundMaterial );
                    boundSphere.position.set(tmpX);
                    break;
                default:
                    var tmpX = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                    var sphereModel = new THREE.Sphere( tmpX, 6);
                    var sphereGeom =  new THREE.SphereGeometry( 6, 32, 16 );
                    var boundMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff, transparent: true, opacity: 0.3 } );
                    var boundSphere = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeom, boundMaterial );
                    boundSphere.position.set(tmpX);
                    break;
            }

            this.home = boundSphere;

            this.draw = function(){
                scene.add(this.home);
            }

            this.setPosition = function(newPos){
                this.home.position.set(newPos);
            }
        }

        var world1 = new worldClass(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
        console.log(world1.home.position);
        world1.setPosition(new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1));
        console.log(world1.home.position);
```

I get the first output : `undefined`, and when I try to change the position I get undefined fields instead of `x: undefined, y:undefined, z:undefined`.
I know that I can use a property for this purpose, but I need to know what's wrong with my class.
I've also tried, successfully, in tricking JS, by adding a "constructor" function to the class, which wrapped the apparently problematic line: `this.position = new THREE.Vector3();`.
But still - I wish I'd understand what is the proper way of dealing with classes in JS.

Comment: Should `this.position.set(newPos);` be `this.position = newPos;`? Also the argument you pass to `new worldClass` is not used as the position, it's stored in `this.shape`, `this.position` is an empty vector.

Comment: @Halcyon - You were right to correct me, I accidentally pasted an old code. Please have another look.

Comment: `boundSphere.position.set(tmpX);` does not seem correct to me. A `Mesh` has no `position` property. What does a `position` on a mesh do?

Comment: You are sending your worldClass constructor a vector? `var world1 = new worldClass(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));` but the switch statement in the worldClass seems to expect a string. Your draw function accesses a variable `scene` which it should not have access to. @Halcyon Mesh should have a position property as it extends Object3D. I have lately been doing more OO three.js and have just been doing it the same as three.js itself, for instance, take a look at how [MESH](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/objects/Mesh.js) extends Object3D

Comment: @2pha - How can I send another argument to the calss' method (newPose), without going over the "constructor"?
Also - why shouldn't `draw` access `scene`?

Comment: Having not tested the code, I think you're just missing a return statement.

Comment: @SeanNovak - I can't see where a `return` statement would fit in, can you explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing setPosition a Vector3, which is setting position.x to a Vector3...

I think I've solved it here, 
http://codepen.io/snovak/pen/OMMoNZ

```
        this.setPosition = function(newPos){
            if(newPos.hasOwnProperty("x") && newPos.hasOwnProperty("y") && newPos.hasOwnProperty("z") ){
               this.home.position.set(newPos.x, newPos.y, newPos.z ) ;
            } else {
              console.log("setPosition requires THREE.Vector3 as arguement");
            }               
        }
```

Comment: Your suggestion did work, but I have 2 questions now: 1. what do you mean by setting position.x to a Vector3? when I check `wordl1.home.position.x` it gives me a scalar.

Comment: 2. Why can't I use `this.home.set(Vector3)` in here? What am I missing? because I did set position using `Vector3` many times before... Say, every time I initialized a `Mesh`.

Comment: Hi @MeirElad, this.home.set() is not a function in this case and this.home.position.set() is looking for 3 numbers, which then sets the object's current instance of Vector3 to your desired coordinates.  They probably don't want you instantiating a bunch of unnecessary objects into memory that the garbage collector is going to have to clean up, which would slow down your application depending on how often this happens.  Ideally, you should be using this.home.position.set(x, y, z);  and not instantiating the Vector3() like I have it in the example.  I wanted to follow your pattern to illustrate.

Comment: I meant `this.home.position.set(Vector3)`, as written in the code I provided in the question. I thought that's a correct way of dealing `position.set`, but apparently I was wrong. You should always `position.set(x, y, z)` as instructed on [Vector3](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Vector3)